# Linker error in Cool Prop using VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

Im getting the linker error while compiling [coolprop c++ source code](http://coolprop.sourceforge.net/)  in VS2010.

Can you help me to resolve this...

```
ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>R134a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::~TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??1TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>REFPROP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::~TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??1TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>FluidClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::~TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??1TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Fluid::~Fluid(void)" (??1Fluid@@UAE@XZ)
1>R407C.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::~TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??1TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>R410A.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::~TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??1TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>R22.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::~TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??1TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>REFPROP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??0TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>R407C.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??0TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Fluid::Fluid(void)" (??0Fluid@@QAE@XZ)
1>R410A.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??0TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>R22.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??0TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
1>R134a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TTSETwoPhaseTableClass::TTSETwoPhaseTableClass(void)" (??0TTSETwoPhaseTableClass@@QAE@XZ)
```